# Hide status bar temporarly in iOS 7

Tags: ios, hide, ios7, statusbar

I want to hide the status bar temporarily in my app. I want it always shown but some times I want to hide it.

I tried this :

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden
{
    return YES;
}
```

But I'm unable to change the state of my status bar once this method is called. Does it exists something to hide or show the status bar when needed?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call `setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate`.